# How do I go about using an exported SVG on a site and how do I make its components interactive?

Tags: html, svg, interactive, interaction

**Reference Image**

[Body svg broken in to components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0XLH.png)

This is an svg of a body separated into components, heads, shoulders knees and toes etc.

**CodePen Example**

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/volcanioo/pen/RLXOar)

```js
window.onload = function () {
    const pieces = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    for (var i = 0; pieces.length; i++) {
        let _piece = pieces[i];
        _piece.onclick = function(t) {
            if (t.target.getAttribute('data-position') != null) document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = t.target.getAttribute('data-position');
            if (t.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-position') != null) document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = t.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-position');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.human-body {
    width: 207px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 240px;
    height: 260px;
    display: block;
    margin: 40px auto;
}
.human-body svg:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.human-body svg:hover path {
    fill: #ff7d16;
}
.human-body svg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    fill: #57c9d5;
}
.human-body svg.head {
    margin-left: -28.5px;
    top: -6px;
}
.human-body svg.shoulder {
    margin-left: -53.5px;
    top: 69px;
}
.human-body svg.arm {
    margin-left: -78px;
    top: 112px;
}
.human-body svg.cheast {
    margin-left: -43.5px;
    top: 88px;
}
.human-body svg.stomach {
    margin-left: -37.5px;
    top: 130px;
}
.human-body svg.legs {
    margin-left: -46.5px;
    top: 205px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.human-body svg.hands {
    margin-left: -102.5px;
    top: 224px;
}
#area {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: Courier New;
    color: #a5a5a5;
}

#area #data {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
    <div class="human-body">
        <svg data-position="head" class="head" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="56.594" height="95.031" viewBox="0 0 56.594 95.031"><path d="M15.92 68.5l8.8 12.546 3.97 13.984-9.254-7.38-4.622-15.848zm27.1 0l-8.8 12.546-3.976 13.988 9.254-7.38 4.622-15.848zm6.11-27.775l.108-11.775-21.16-14.742L8.123 26.133 8.09 40.19l-3.24.215 1.462 9.732 5.208 1.81 2.36 11.63 9.72 11.018 10.856-.324 9.56-10.37 1.918-11.952 5.207-1.81 1.342-9.517zm-43.085-1.84l-.257-13.82L28.226 11.9l23.618 15.755-.216 10.37 4.976-17.085L42.556 2.376 25.49 0 10.803 3.673.002 24.415z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="shoulder" class="shoulder" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="109.532" height="46.594" viewBox="0 0 109.532 46.594"><path d="M38.244-.004l1.98 9.232-11.653 2.857-7.474-2.637zm33.032 0l-1.98 9.232 11.653 2.857 7.474-2.637zm21.238 10.54l4.044-2.187 12.656 14 .07 5.33S92.76 10.66 92.515 10.535zm-1.285.58c-.008.28 17.762 18.922 17.762 18.922l.537 16.557-6.157-10.55L91.5 30.988 83.148 15.6zm-74.224-.58L12.962 8.35l-12.656 14-.062 5.325s16.52-17.015 16.764-17.14zm1.285.58C18.3 11.396.528 30.038.528 30.038L-.01 46.595l6.157-10.55 11.87-5.056L26.374 15.6z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="arm" class="arm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="156.344" height="119.25" viewBox="0 0 156.344 119.25"><path d="M21.12 56.5a1.678 1.678 0 0 1-.427.33l.935 8.224 12.977-13.89 1.2-8.958A168.2 168.2 0 0 0 21.12 56.5zm1.387 12.522l-18.07 48.91 5.757 1.333 19.125-39.44 3.518-22.047zm-5.278-18.96l2.638 18.74-17.2 46.023L.01 113.05l6.644-35.518zm118.015 6.44a1.678 1.678 0 0 0 .426.33l-.934 8.222-12.977-13.89-1.2-8.958A168.2 168.2 0 0 1 135.24 56.5zm-1.39 12.52l18.073 48.91-5.758 1.333-19.132-39.44-3.52-22.05zm5.28-18.96l-2.64 18.74 17.2 46.023 2.658-1.775-6.643-35.518zm-103.1-12.323a1.78 1.78 0 0 1 .407-.24l3.666-27.345L33.07.015l-7.258 10.58-6.16 37.04.566 4.973a151.447 151.447 0 0 1 15.808-14.87zm84.3 0a1.824 1.824 0 0 0-.407-.24l-3.666-27.345L123.3.015l7.258 10.58 6.16 37.04-.566 4.973a151.447 151.447 0 0 0-15.822-14.87zM22.288 8.832l-3.3 35.276-2.2-26.238zm111.79 0l3.3 35.276 2.2-26.238z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="cheast" class="cheast" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="86.594" height="45.063" viewBox="0 0 86.594 45.063"><path d="M19.32 0l-9.225 16.488-10.1 5.056 6.15 4.836 4.832 14.07 11.2 4.616 17.85-8.828-4.452-34.7zm47.934 0l9.225 16.488 10.1 5.056-6.15 4.836-4.833 14.07-11.2 4.616-17.844-8.828 4.45-34.7z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="stomach" class="stomach" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="75.25" height="107.594" viewBox="0 0 75.25 107.594"><path d="M19.25 7.49l16.6-7.5-.5 12.16-14.943 7.662zm-10.322 8.9l6.9 3.848-.8-9.116zm5.617-8.732L1.32 2.15 6.3 15.6zm-8.17 9.267l9.015 5.514 1.54 11.028-8.795-5.735zm15.53 5.89l.332 8.662 12.286-2.665.664-11.826zm14.61 84.783L33.28 76.062l-.08-20.53-11.654-5.736-1.32 37.5zM22.735 35.64L22.57 46.3l11.787 3.166.166-16.657zm-14.16-5.255L16.49 35.9l1.1 11.25-8.8-7.06zm8.79 22.74l-9.673-7.28-.84 9.78L-.006 68.29l10.564 14.594 5.5.883 1.98-20.735zM56 7.488l-16.6-7.5.5 12.16 14.942 7.66zm10.32 8.9l-6.9 3.847.8-9.116zm-5.617-8.733L73.93 2.148l-4.98 13.447zm8.17 9.267l-9.015 5.514-1.54 11.03 8.8-5.736zm-15.53 5.89l-.332 8.662-12.285-2.665-.664-11.827zm-14.61 84.783l3.234-31.536.082-20.532 11.65-5.735 1.32 37.5zm13.78-71.957l.166 10.66-11.786 3.168-.166-16.657zm14.16-5.256l-7.915 5.514-1.1 11.25 8.794-7.06zm-8.79 22.743l9.673-7.28.84 9.78 6.862 12.66-10.564 14.597-5.5.883-1.975-20.74z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="legs" class="legs" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="93.626" height="286.625" viewBox="0 0 93.626 286.625"><path d="M17.143 138.643l-.664 5.99 4.647 5.77 1.55 9.1 3.1 1.33 2.655-13.755 1.77-4.88-1.55-3.107zm20.582.444l-3.32 9.318-7.082 13.755 1.77 12.647 5.09-14.2 4.205-7.982zm-26.557-12.645l5.09 27.29-3.32-1.777-2.656 8.875zm22.795 42.374l-1.55 4.88-3.32 20.634-.442 27.51 4.65 26.847-.223-34.39 4.87-13.754.663-15.087zM23.34 181.24l1.106 41.267 8.853 33.28-9.628-4.55-16.045-57.8 5.533-36.384zm15.934 80.536l-.664 18.415-1.55 6.435h-4.647l-1.327-4.437-1.55-.222.332 4.437-5.864-1.778-1.55-.887-6.64-1.442-.22-5.214 6.418-10.87 4.426-5.548 10.844-4.437zM13.63 3.076v22.476l15.71 31.073 9.923 30.85L38.23 66.1zm25.49 30.248l.118-.148-.793-2.024L21.9 12.992l-1.242-.44L31.642 40.93zM32.865 44.09l6.812 17.6 2.274-21.596-1.344-3.43zM6.395 61.91l.827 25.34 12.816 35.257-3.928 10.136L3.5 88.133zM30.96 74.69l.345.826 6.47 15.48-4.177 38.342-6.594-3.526 5.715-35.7zm45.5 63.953l.663 5.99-4.647 5.77-1.55 9.1-3.1 1.33-2.655-13.755-1.77-4.88 1.55-3.107zm-20.582.444l3.32 9.318 7.08 13.755-1.77 12.647-5.09-14.2-4.2-7.987zm3.762 29.73l1.55 4.88 3.32 20.633.442 27.51-4.648 26.847.22-34.39-4.867-13.754-.67-15.087zm10.623 12.424l-1.107 41.267-8.852 33.28 9.627-4.55 16.046-57.8-5.533-36.384zM54.33 261.777l.663 18.415 1.546 6.435h4.648l1.328-4.437 1.55-.222-.333 4.437 5.863-1.778 1.55-.887 6.638-1.442.222-5.214-6.418-10.868-4.426-5.547-10.844-4.437zm25.643-258.7v22.476L64.26 56.625l-9.923 30.85L55.37 66.1zM54.48 33.326l-.118-.15.793-2.023L71.7 12.993l1.24-.44L61.96 40.93zm6.255 10.764l-6.812 17.6-2.274-21.595 1.344-3.43zm26.47 17.82l-.827 25.342-12.816 35.256 3.927 10.136 12.61-44.51zM62.64 74.693l-.346.825-6.47 15.48 4.178 38.342 6.594-3.527-5.715-35.7zm19.792 51.75l-5.09 27.29 3.32-1.776 2.655 8.875zM9.495-.007l.827 21.373-7.028 42.308-3.306-34.155zm2.068 27.323L26.24 59.707l3.307 26-6.2 36.58L9.91 85.046l-.827-38.342zM84.103-.01l-.826 21.375 7.03 42.308 3.306-34.155zm-2.066 27.325L67.36 59.707l-3.308 26 6.2 36.58 13.436-37.24.827-38.34z"/></svg>
        <svg data-position="hands" class="hands" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="205" height="38.938" viewBox="0 0 205 38.938"><path d="M21.255-.002l2.88 6.9 8.412 1.335.664 12.458-4.427 17.8-2.878-.22 2.8-11.847-2.99-.084-4.676 12.6-3.544-.446 4.4-12.736-3.072-.584-5.978 13.543-4.428-.445 6.088-14.1-2.1-1.25-7.528 12.012-3.764-.445L12.4 12.9l-1.107-1.78L.665 15.57 0 13.124l8.635-7.786zm162.49 0l-2.88 6.9-8.412 1.335-.664 12.458 4.427 17.8 2.878-.22-2.8-11.847 2.99-.084 4.676 12.6 3.544-.446-4.4-12.736 3.072-.584 5.978 13.543 4.428-.445-6.088-14.1 2.1-1.25 7.528 12.012 3.764-.445L192.6 12.9l1.107-1.78 10.628 4.45.665-2.447-8.635-7.786z"/></svg>
    </div>

    <div id="area">
        Area: <span id="data"></span>
    </div>
```

This CodePen is an example of a similar svg of a body broken into components that the user can interact with, just not broken down to as many parts as I need.

**My Issue**

I'm looking to make an svg interactive similar to the CodePen example above, the only experience I have is making them in Inkscape and using them as img src="blah.svg".
I understand the JS part but the rest eludes me.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried exporting my svg from Inkscape, opening it in my text editor and modifying it using the CodePen example as a base.

**My Question**

How do I go about making my svg work like the one shown in the CodePen example?

i.e highlightable, clickable body components

If you can talk me through the process of 'drawing' my svg in html, or direct me to somewhere I can garner the info I would be most grateful. Sorry if I haven't given enough info but I'm not 100% sure what to ask.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

It's letting me add it as an edit to the question but not as a reply. As for further clarification, all I'm really after is to use my SVG and have it behave in a similar manner to that shown in the CodePen example. Sorry again if I'm not clear in my question but not knowing much on the subject is making it hard to know what ask.

Here's my SVGs code:

```
  <svg
 xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
 xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
 xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
 width="207"
 height="100%"
 viewBox="0 0 210 297"
 version="1.1"
 id="svg8"
 sodipodi:docname="body.svg"
 inkscape:version="1.0 (4035a4fb49, 2020-05-01)">
<defs
   id="defs2" />
<sodipodi:namedview
   id="base"
   pagecolor="#ffffff"
   bordercolor="#666666"
   borderopacity="1.0"
   inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
   inkscape:pageshadow="2"
   inkscape:zoom="1.979899"
   inkscape:cx="342.84693"
   inkscape:cy="318.08859"
   inkscape:document-units="mm"
   inkscape:current-layer="Full body"
   inkscape:document-rotation="0"
   showgrid="false"
   inkscape:window-width="1680"
   inkscape:window-height="1028"
   inkscape:window-x="1432"
   inkscape:window-y="-8"
   inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
<metadata
   id="metadata5">
  <rdf:RDF>
    <cc:Work
       rdf:about="">
      <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
      <dc:type
         rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      <dc:title />
    </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g
   inkscape:groupmode="layer"
   id="Full body"
   inkscape:label="SVG"
   style="display:inline">
  <path
     data-part="head"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.266679px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 103.62544,15.035459 c 8.26218,-0.100026 12.48099,6.901836 12.30482,15.304071 l 1.89306,0.200053 -0.54089,5.30141 -3.31285,1.20032 -1.01412,6.601756 -5.74674,6.201649 H 100.8535 L 95.039139,43.342989 93.822162,37.041313 90.847361,36.2411 89.968474,30.139477 91.793915,29.939424 C 90.566704,21.137082 96.583771,15.135486 103.62544,15.035459 Z"
     id="head"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccccccccc" />
  <path
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     data-part="left-chest"
     d="m 107.67685,62.206983 9.35444,-1.002263 c 9.45048,11.711603 7.53344,12.764242 7.02335,23.10735 l -8.26046,2.939965 -10.79003,-5.668014 z"
     id="left-chest"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="left-ribs"
     id="left-ribs"
     d="m 124.6708,86.595325 -8.78275,2.985031 -11.00856,-4.77195 0.70871,16.914434 8.78795,2.59859 6.66183,-3.35454 0.99219,-6.614585 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="left-oblique"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc"
     id="left-oblique"
     d="m 121.41479,103.09365 -6.62294,3.23106 -0.24765,8.83519 6.95678,-4.11049 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-chest"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccc"
     id="right-chest"
     d="M 100.18164,62.206983 90.8272,61.20472 c -9.450474,11.711603 -7.533438,12.764242 -7.023344,23.10735 l 8.260454,2.939965 10.79002,-5.668014 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-ribs"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 83.254457,86.595325 8.782743,2.985031 11.00856,-4.77195 -0.70871,16.914434 -8.787944,2.59859 -6.66183,-3.35454 -0.992187,-6.614585 z"
     id="right-ribs" />
  <path
     data-part="right-oblique"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 86.784429,103.09365 6.622937,3.23106 0.04725,8.83519 -6.756326,-4.11049 z"
     id="right-oblique"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="stomach"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 104.13489,103.45597 9.18739,2.93997 -0.3675,9.65511 -8.64711,4.24766 -9.326763,-4.31447 -0.200451,-9.75534 z"
     id="stomach"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="hips"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 86.53424,113.55526 -0.172775,4.56176 -4.109268,7.34992 22.276883,22.89068 21.05419,-22.75705 -4.04245,-7.34991 -0.51162,-4.50068 -16.64899,9.18936 z"
     id="hips"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="right-shoulder"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccc"
     id="right-shoulder"
     d="m 94.861265,46.438079 -0.46772,2.338609 -14.777371,6.280833 -7.483547,7.951269 3.87541,3.274051 6.614914,1.603619 4.677217,-8.68626 6.492017,-3.474503 8.352155,6.013564 -2.204967,-8.418992 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-upper-arm"
     id="right-upper-arm"
     d="m 82.254225,69.42326 -6.629288,-1.74322 -4.112119,-3.537773 -2.619761,37.614113 5.437376,-6.537854 4.126128,8.870844 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="right-elbow"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 74.139256,97.119063 -5.111529,5.746297 3.040191,9.48807 6.247425,-5.77971 z"
     id="right-elbow"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="right-lower-arm"
     id="right-lower-arm"
     d="m 78.007698,108.5183 -6.575444,6.08677 -3.14793,-11.22858 -6.331117,15.59152 -2.348898,17.6786 3.610917,-0.82867 1.99665,3.75127 11.306845,-18.80582 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="right-wrist"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc"
     id="right-wrist"
     d="m 62.671097,137.09256 1.87089,3.842 -0.55125,2.47225 -4.092557,-0.25057 -1.95441,-3.69166 0.95215,-1.38646 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-hand"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccccccccccccccccccc"
     id="right-hand"
     d="m 63.28856,144.71571 -4.276307,-0.26727 -2.37202,-4.44335 -7.550354,3.00678 -4.777437,4.34313 0.4009,1.46998 5.679477,-2.27179 0.935437,1.06907 -6.414464,12.12736 2.204977,0.10023 4.309717,-6.74856 0.96885,0.90203 -3.274047,7.6506 2.405427,0.30067 3.44109,-7.68399 1.837477,0.26726 -2.572467,7.38332 2.104747,0.30068 2.67269,-7.3165 1.83748,-0.13364 -1.83748,6.9156 1.9043,0.20046 2.639277,-10.28988 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="left-shoulder"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 113.31154,46.438079 0.46772,2.338609 14.77738,6.280833 7.48355,7.951269 -3.87541,3.274051 -6.61492,1.603619 -4.67722,-8.68626 -6.49202,-3.474503 -8.35217,6.013564 2.20497,-8.418992 z"
     id="left-shoulder"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="left-upper-arm"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 126.27753,69.42326 6.62929,-1.74322 4.11213,-3.537773 2.61976,37.614113 -5.43738,-6.537857 -4.12613,8.870847 z"
     id="left-upper-arm" />
  <path
     data-part="left-elbow"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc"
     id="left-elbow"
     d="m 134.3925,97.119063 5.11154,5.746297 -3.04019,9.48807 -6.24744,-5.77971 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="left-lower-arm"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccc"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 130.59255,108.5183 6.57545,6.08677 3.14793,-11.22858 6.33112,15.59152 2.33744,17.75995 -3.61092,-0.82867 -1.99665,3.75127 -11.29539,-18.88717 z"
     id="left-lower-arm" />
  <path
     data-part="left-wrist"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 145.92916,137.09256 -1.87089,3.842 0.55125,2.47225 4.09256,-0.25057 1.95441,-3.69166 -0.95215,-1.38646 z"
     id="left-wrist"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="left-hand"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 145.3117,144.71571 4.27631,-0.26727 2.37202,-4.44335 7.55036,3.00678 4.77744,4.34313 -0.4009,1.46998 -5.67948,-2.27179 -0.93544,1.06907 6.41447,12.12736 -2.20498,0.10023 -4.30972,-6.74856 -0.96885,0.90203 3.27405,7.6506 -2.40543,0.30067 -3.44109,-7.68399 -1.83748,0.26726 2.57247,7.38332 -2.10475,0.30068 -2.67269,-7.3165 -1.83748,-0.13364 1.83748,6.9156 -1.9043,0.20046 -2.63928,-10.28988 z"
     id="left-hand"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccccccccccccccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="left-upper-leg"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 125.61668,128.28937 -18.97614,21.64883 2.93996,54.38935 7.61719,-5.34539 7.21627,5.07812 4.94449,-26.05878 1.33635,-33.67596 z"
     id="left-upper-leg"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="left-knee"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 109.71414,215.95915 -0.26727,-8.55263 7.88445,-5.61266 7.61718,5.7463 -0.13363,8.01808 -7.21628,5.87993 z"
     id="left-knee"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="left-lower-leg"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 125.10409,217.59555 -7.43868,6.40972 -8.15172,-6.31425 -1.00226,16.16981 0.53454,9.08717 3.20723,7.88445 -1.45279,22.28933 3.29712,-4.89581 3.50106,3.45351 8.81989,-33.0078 z"
     id="left-lower-leg"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="left-ankle"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 114.24018,270.32595 -3.13538,5.07176 4.02155,3.85479 2.31162,-5.53164 z"
     id="left-ankle"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
  <path
     data-part="left-foot"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cssccccccc"
     id="left-foot"
     d="m 112.86233,294.63782 c -0.0969,1.04516 2.67851,1.02047 2.87228,0.095 0.27172,-1.29783 0.55497,-0.37031 2.1314,-0.0673 2.85703,0.54923 5.21256,-0.85616 7.29072,-2.56682 0.82712,-1.04681 0.6914,-2.09361 0.26727,-3.14042 l -6.28084,-9.42125 -0.69854,-3.43893 -2.5755,5.91117 -4.27632,-3.80857 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-upper-leg"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cccccccc"
     id="right-upper-leg"
     d="m 82.612584,128.28937 18.976116,21.64883 -2.939951,54.38935 -7.617178,-5.34539 -7.216267,5.07812 -4.944487,-26.05878 -1.33635,-33.67596 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-knee"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccc"
     id="right-knee"
     d="m 98.515109,215.95915 0.26727,-8.55263 -7.884438,-5.61266 -7.617177,5.7463 0.13363,8.01808 7.216277,5.87993 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-lower-leg"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccc"
     id="right-lower-leg"
     d="m 82.839165,217.59555 7.438674,6.40972 8.151717,-6.31425 1.00226,16.16981 -0.53454,9.08717 -3.20723,7.88445 1.500039,22.28933 -3.344366,-4.89581 -3.50106,3.45351 -8.819884,-33.0078 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-ankle"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc"
     id="right-ankle"
     d="m 93.703069,270.32595 3.135377,5.07176 -4.021547,3.85479 -2.31162,-5.53164 z"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" />
  <path
     data-part="right-foot"
     style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
     d="m 95.080919,294.63782 c 0.0969,1.04516 -2.678507,1.02047 -2.872277,0.095 -0.27172,-1.29783 -0.55497,-0.37031 -2.1314,-0.0673 -2.857027,0.54923 -5.212557,-0.85616 -7.290714,-2.56682 -0.82712,-1.04681 -0.6914,-2.09361 -0.26727,-3.14042 l 6.280834,-9.42125 0.69854,-3.43893 2.5755,5.91117 4.276317,-3.80857 z"
     id="right-foot"
     sodipodi:nodetypes="cssccccccc" />
</g>
```

Comment: Your CodePen link points to the imgur image again.

Comment: Whoops, thanks will edit that.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Can you clarify what the issue is?

Comment: Basically I'm looking to make a version of the CodePen example but using my own svg. I need to have more body parts/components than the CodePen example has such as ankles, knees etc. but I have no real clue as to go about doing this. Hope that clarifies things, if not, sorry :(

Comment: It is still not clear what you are asking. You say you are wanting to get "highlightable, clickable body components", but you also say "I understand the JS part but the rest eludes me". What specifically do you mean by "the rest"? Are you needing a better understanding of "how to make a polygon in SVG"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit to address OP comments:

Again, it's not clear what you're asking.

> …still a little lost as when viewing the SVG code there's a whole lot of additional stuff…

SVGs exported from GUI apps frequently have a bunch of unnecessary junk in them--groups, transforms that cancel each other out, defs that aren't necessary, etc..

"How do I clean up this SVG?" is too broad of a question for SO, especially if we can't see the SVG. But the basics of SVG are not particularly complicated. Check out [how to use a path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path) and you’ll be able to do most of what you seem to want to do.

'sodipodi' is Inkscape's predecessor so I'd assume any references to it in the SVG are just metadata used by Inkscape if you open it there. (Again, impossible to say without seeing it.)

`<defs>` [declares reusable elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/defs).

> It seems like my entire image is grouped as 1 SVG tag rather than each part within an SVG tag

Is there a particular reason you need each part to be its own separate SVG?

---

### Original Answer

Inkscape has an XML Editor view that allows you to edit attributes associated with a particular element--a shape or group or whatever. You can use this to assign sensible ids and data attributes that will be preserved when you export to SVG.

[image: Annotated Inkscape Screenshot]

---

Labeling the parts in this way makes accessing them in javascript fairly trivial, lets you do all your edits in Inkscape instead of trying to do SVG math in a text editor, and it can all live in a single SVG (unless there's some reason they need to be separate?).

(I'm not using the IDs and they could be omitted here; just added them to show that you *could* assign IDs if you needed them for whatever reason.)

Note: Inkscape has several SVG export options. I'm using "Optimized" here because in my cursory tests it produced the most usable output.

```js
// find everything in the svg with a data-part attribute
const parts = document.querySelectorAll('svg [data-part]');

// register a click listener on all the parts
parts.forEach(p => p.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  // get the data-part value from the clicked element
  const {part} = e.target.dataset
  
  // do whatever you need to do with it
  console.log(part);
}))
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-width=".26458">
  <rect id="bluerect" x="10" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="#00f" data-part="square"/>
  <circle id="redcircle" cx="42" cy="20" r="10" fill="#f00" data-part="circle"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I'm after, unfortunately something's come up IRL and I won't have time to actually read this properly for a few hours, sorry and thanks again.

Comment: I kinda see what you're getting at but I'm still a little lost as when viewing the SVG code there's a whole lot of additional stuff, I would share the SVG code but when I try to it says "Too long by 13709 characters" lol. Some of the things I'm unsure about are at the top of the code 'sodipodi', 'defs' and 'rdf' tags. It seems like my entire image is grouped as 1 SVG tag rather than each part within an SVG tag, if that makes sense.

Comment: I think the link to mozilla you provided is along this lines of what I'm after in terms of learning how to draw and use SVGs, thank you kindly. 

I've also added my SVG code snippet to my question should you want to have a look, I was too tired last night to think editing my question to include it would work. You'll see all the added stuff I mention at the top and sprinkled throughout. 

Regarding the SVG being a group and not separate parts, my noob guess was based on the CodePen example which made me think I would need individual parts, so when I saw it was a group it confused me a bit.

Comment: The [path commands reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#path_commands) will be of particular interest if you decide to write SVGs by hand, but I'm not sure why you'd want to go that route in this case.

Comment: Thanks to your assistance I've made some small progress in my understanding of SVGs  and a little progress in making this work. I am, however, now faced with an issue where the hovering/clicking is only working if I hover over the stroke of the body part, rather than the fill, not sure how to resolve this. I can slap it together in a CodePen for you to check out if that'll help (and if you're still willing to assist)? RE: writing SVGs, I was thinking by knowing how to write them I would possibly gain a fuller understanding of how things work.

Comment: Hold on, I just realised that all my paths have a style setting 'fill' to none, I imagine that's my issue, will tinker and report back.

Comment: Yep. No fill would've been my first guess on the no hover/click problem. I'll take a look if you want but I can't say exactly when I'll be able to get to it. I've opened a [live session on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/live/4x6j3k0) where we can discuss this. I'll leave it open and check in on it periodically to see if you've joined.

Comment: Okay so I tinkered and it was most certainly because I had used no fill in Inkscape. It output the styling for fill to be none in the code. I've marked your answer as accepted and I wish I could vote you up but I'm not rep worthy yet, thank you for your patience and assistance :)